# node: getting error importing CommonJS module however I try to import it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, commonjs

I have a local node module, @em/inVis in my company whose index.d.ts file looks as follows:

```
import UWeb from "./UWeb";
import UWebParams from "./UWebParams";
export { UWeb, UWebParams };
```

elsewhere within the app, it's used as follows in typescript files

```
import { UWeb, UWebParams } from "@em/inVis";
```

when I try to do that in my TS file, I get the node error:

> SyntaxError: Named export 'UWeb' not found. The requested module '@em/inVis' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all
> module.exports as named exports. CommonJS modules can always be
> imported via the default export, for example using:
>
> import pkg from '@em/inVis'; const { UWeb, UWebParams } = pkg;

so when I try using that approach suggested above, I am getting the node error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module not sure
> what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just add `"type":"module"` to your package.json file.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue and it already has "type":"module" set.

Comment: @PEZO I also had this issue (and already had `"type": "module"`), and when I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, I realized that the issue only happened when the directory I was importing from was symlinked. That is, I had `import { foo, bar } from "./baz/util.js";`, and when `baz` was a symlink to another directory, it gave this error, but when `baz` was a real directory it worked. No idea why it behaves this way, it's pretty annoying. I'm just going to use hard links instead of symlinks I guess.